# Cannot integrate UpdateManager of Squirrel.Windows to the Program.cs

Tags: c#, squirrel.windows

I am trying to learn Squirrel.Windows so I can use it in my project so I am using [this guide](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows/blob/develop/docs/getting-started/0-overview.md) as a starter. They are using this simple [Windows form project from their Github](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows/blob/develop/docs/getting-started/example/MyApp.zip), so people who wants to follow can download it.

I can successfully run the project before editing anything. However, I am currently stuck in this [early part of the guide](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows/blob/develop/docs/getting-started/1-integrating.md#basic-squirrelwindows-update-code). I followed the instructions given in a way like this:

```
namespace MyApp
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static async Task Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());

            using (var mgr = new UpdateManager("MyApp_Root_Here\\Releases"))
            {
                await mgr.UpdateApp();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this error came out:

> Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

I really don't know what was wrong with what I did.

---

### EDIT :

After the above problem being *temporarily* fixed with the help of **@Junior** in the comments. I said temporarily because the error is only gone in the `Debug` build but no on the `Release` build.

Comment: What visual studio version are you using? (the year)

Comment: @Junior, VS 2017 Pro

Comment: I suspect you need to enable C# 7.1 in Visual Studio. `async Task Main` is only supported in 2017 after an update.
Have a read of this https://www.danielcrabtree.com/blog/329/c-sharp-7-1-everything-you-need-to-know

Comment: Also put `Application.Run(new Form1());` after the update check, because if you have it before the update check - it won't run until you close form1.

Comment: @Junior, thank you, the 7.1 version helped.

Comment: @Junior, you have any idea why the same error still shows on Release build even if its no longer shows on Debug build?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213909/discussion-between-lindasingh-and-junior).

Comment: Step 1 of that link I provided earlier, try that step again after switching to release mode. I think it only applies to one at a time.